# force start java jnlp with java 64 bit

Tags: java, 64-bit, jnlp

We are running **windows 8.1** with both **java 1.8.0_77** **32** and **64**.

If we don't force to start with `c:\program files\java\jre1.8.0_77\bin\javaws.exe`, the webpplication starts by default in 32bit.

If we use a `Xmx` bigger than **1G** the jnlp starting fails. 
we tried adding `-d64, -J-d64`, but nothing was successful. We cannot remove the 32bit version.

Is there a way to force to start jnlp with 64bit java version?

Comment: Maybe changing the default `JNLPFile` file association to launch the 64bit java webstart app? The use of the 32bit JRE is pretty much determined by this registry entry.

Comment: I already did this try... I don't know why this is starting with the 32b version. I doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

change your PATH environment variable

Comment: Hi, my environmental variable is poiting to C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath in which there are 3 symbolic links pointing to the 64 bit java version.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643992/how-to-distinguish-32-bit-from-64-bit-java-version-in-jnlp-files

if it's your jnlp, you can specify the architecture in the file