# How to load the jar based on JRE bits in JNLP?

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit, jnlp

I'm using SWT jar in the application and launching my application using JNLP, the problem here is I need to load SWT jar dynamically based on JRE bits(32 or 64 bit).

Is there any way to load jars based on JRE bits.

[Tried this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643992/how-to-distinguish-32-bit-from-64-bit-java-version-in-jnlp-files) but it didn't solve my problem

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to distinguish 32 bit from 64 bit java version in jnlp files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643992/how-to-distinguish-32-bit-from-64-bit-java-version-in-jnlp-files)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had tried that solution, but that didn't solve my problem. I need JRE bits not OS bit version.

Comment: Very well, that's why it was a "possible duplicate" ^^ You should add the difference in your quesiton I think.